# Anat and Ištar (west Semitic deity), did these deities derive from the same Semitic deity?

Tags: mesopotamia, arabic, inanna, akkadian

Apparently, Astarte/Athtart/Ashtart the Phoenician/Carthaginian goddess was a variation of (or that she simply derived from the same religious figure) the Babylonian Ishtar (who was herself a fusion of Inanna and some Akkadian goddess named Ištar), but what of Anat(h)?

As it was shown in the texts regarding Baal, another Phoenician deity sometimes depicted as Astarte's consort, Anat and Ishtar share various similarities as both were worshipped as war deities and the former, though not as explicitly as the latter, seemed to have some attributes that were considered sexual (it was described that she and Baal grabbed each others' genitals, similar to the erotic description in Inanna and Dumuzid's courtship).

Another similarity was when Anat complained to El, which was itself similar to Inanna's threat to Anu...and last was her descent to the underworld, though she wasn't trapped there as Inanna/Ishtar was in Sumerian myths, her goal was the same: to find her consort, and that, was almost identical to the earlier myths of Inanna when she sought not to take her sister's throne but to resurrect her lover Dumuzid.

Besides all that, I read the article [here](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Astarte-ancient-deity) which claimed Astarte and Anant may originally be a same deity, but ultimately split into two.

Their similarities seem to be the aspects of fertility, war, [lions](https://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-35720366), and crescent. **To ask the question more precisely, could Al-Lat, Anat/Anath, Ishtar/Astarte be seen as the "descendants" of an early Semitic goddess associated with love, war, and sexuality?**

Answer (score -1):

Sounds very much like Ningirsu, Mother of Eannatum, in historical accounts

**Eannatum**

> Eannatum, the ensi of Lagash, who was granted might by Enlil, who constantly is nourished by Ninhursag with her milk, whose name Ningirsu had pronounced, who was chosen by Nanshe in her heart, the son of Akurgal, the ensi of Lagash, conquered the land of Elam, conquered Urua, conquered Umma, conquered Ur. At that time, he built a well made of baked bricks for Ningirsu, in his wide temple courtyard. Eananatum's god is Shulutula. Then did Ningirsu love Eannatum".
> [Eannatum and Ningirsu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eannatum#Conquest_outside_Sumer)

**Adam and Eve**

Or, Adam and Eve in biblical accounts.

And no, not the same person.

Mother and son.

Eannatum is son of Enlil and Ningirsu, and Ningirsu is wife of Enlil.

And Eannatum did not come from his mothers rib. Though she did breast feed him, to nourish him, and also gave him her heart. (Did not literally give him her heart, however)

Eannatum is historically recognised as being the worlds first ever emperor. And was crowned by his father, Enlil.

And no, it is actually east semitic origins.

What later became the Semitic speaking Hebrew Neo-assyrian empire nearly 1500 years later, all kicked off in Kish, in 2600bc.

**Eastern Semitic**

> The East Semetic nature of these and other early names associated with Kish reveals that its population had a strong Semitic (Akkadian speaking) component from the dawn of recorded history.
> [First dynasty of Kish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kish_(Sumer)#First_Dynasty_of_Kish)